# Erro na hora de cadastrar dados no banco de dados :(

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

estou tentando fazer um sistemas de cadastros de empresas, porém não funciona. Eu estou fazendo tudo certo ao meu ver. O banco está igual, as variáveis estão certas e as funções também. Não sei o que está errado. Alguém pode me ajudar? (Obs: sou iniciante em programação PHP).

```
<?php
// incluindo e fazendo conexão com o banco de dados
require_once "../action/server.php";

// iniciar a sessão - para poder usar variaves de sessão
session_start();

// Verificar se a variavel usuario já foi configurada pelo method post
if ( isset( $_POST["nome"] ) ) {
    $nome                   = $_POST["nome"];
    $email                  = $_POST["email"];
    $telefone               = $_POST["telefone"];
    $tipo_empresa           = $_POST["tipo_empresa"];
    $cnpj                   = $_POST["cnpj"]; 
    $endereco               = $_POST["endereco"]; 
    $complemento            = $_POST["complemento"];
    $numero                 = $_POST["numero"]; 
    $cidade                 = $_POST["cidade"]; 
    $uf                     = $_POST["uf"];
    $cep                    = $_POST["cep"]; 
    $uf                     = $_POST["uf"]; 
    $cidade                 = $_POST["cidade"]; 


    // inserir os dados no banco
    $cadastrar_empresa  = "INSERT INTO ds_empresa";
    $cadastrar_empresa .= "(nome, email, telefone, tipo_empresa, cnpj, endereco, complemento, numero, cidade, uf, cep, senha) ";
    $cadastrar_empresa .= "VALUES ";
    $cadastrar_empresa .= "('$nome', '$email', '$telefone', '$tipo_empresa', '$cnpj', '$endereco', '$complemento', '$numero', '$cidade', '$uf', '$cep', '$senha') ";

    echo "$cadastrar_empresa"; 

    $operacao_cadastrar_empresa = mysqli_query($conecta, $cadastrar_empresa);
    if ( !$operacao_cadastrar_empresa ) {
        die("Cadastro não foi feito! Erro:  " . mysqli_connect_errno());
    } else {
        header("location: login_empresa.php");
    }
}
```

?>

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Cadastro de Empresa</title>
```

Cadastro de Empresa

```
                <!-- (nome, email, senha, cnpj, cep, telefone, complemento, numero, categoria, tipo_empresa, uf, cidade --> 

                <form  action="cadastro_empresa.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputEmail4">Confirmar Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Confirmar Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tipo_empresa">Tipo de Empresa: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tipo_empresa" name="tipo_empresa" placeholder="Tipo da Sua Empresa...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telefone">Telefone Fixo:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="uf">Estado</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uf" name="uf" placeholder="Estado">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cidade" name="cidade" placeholder="Sua Cidade">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cep">CEP</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cep" name="cep" placeholder="Seu CEP">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="endereco">Endereço</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco" name="endereco" placeholder="Seu Endereço">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="numero">Número</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero" name="numero" placeholder="Seu Número">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="complemento">Complemento</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complemento" name="complemento" placeholder="Complemento">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cnpj" name="cnpj" placeholder="Seu CNPJ">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
                    </form>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- JavaScript (Opcional) -->
<!-- jQuery primeiro, depois Popper.js, depois Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Código da configuração do banco:

```
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$banco = "db_ipac";

// Realizando conexão com o Banco
$conecta = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);

// Verificando se ocorreu algum erro na conexão
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    die("Conexão falhou: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
}
```

?>

Comment: Mostra o código do cadastro_empresa.php ? Se possível a tabela para ver os campos do banco também

Comment: A página do código é essa mesma da pergunta. Eu to enviando o form para a mesma página.

Comment: Banco: CREATE TABLE `ds_empresa` (
  `id_empresa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_empresa` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cnpj` char(14) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_empresa_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `complemento` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uf` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cep` char(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Quando tu da o echo do $cadastrar_empresa, tem como mostrar o resultado aqui?

Comment: Mais uma coisa que percebi, se aquele dump da table que tu postou no comentário está igual ao seu banco local então vai dar erro na sua query pois esta faltando 2 váriaveis obrigatórias, id_empresa e tipo_empresa_id. Acredito que tu queria que o id_emrpesa fosse auto_increment e o tipo_empresa_id é uma foreign_key de outra tabela.

Comment: Oi. A variavel $uf está repetida e está faltando preencher a coluna "senha". Verifique.